# Restricting code in displaying datas

Tags: mysql

```
$result=mysql_query("Select $st from `jb_student` where `Sno`=56");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<table>
      <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>MOBILE</th>
      </tr>";

echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

In the above code, I am retriving datas from database based on string $st. For example, If I dont want Mobile, Only Name and Email should be return, how can I restrict the code. Please help me.

Comment: remove the table header for MOBILE and also the table cell containing $row[2] from the HTML

Comment: @Bruce I think you didnt understand my question. $st string is based on checkbox selection in its previous page. If I selected only Name and Email, both values alone displayed, rest should not be displayed.

Comment: @Sarathy In your question you wrote "If I dont want Mobile, Only Name and Email should be return". Now you say "If I selected only Name and Email, both values alone displayed, rest should not be displayed" and this is not what you want. Please rephrase your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your solution is to edit two things:

- What goes in the select statement related to columns.
- How many columns you output in your `<table>`.

> If I dont want Mobile, Only Name and Email should be return, how can I
>   restrict the code

**You would change the value of $st to contain the columns you want.**

```
$st = " name, email ";
```

So, then your final executed query will be:

```
$result=mysql_query("Select name, email from `jb_student` where `Sno`=56");
```

**You would change the echo code for the table**

```
echo "<table>
      <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      </tr>";

echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

*PS: Function with mysql_* is the old way to run mysql queries. Have a look at PDO...*